# Is there a way to duplicate an entire report in pentaho report designer?

Tags: copy, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to re-vamp an already created report in Pentaho Report Designer and instead of starting over was hoping to duplicate the report and then make edits in the duplicated version. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the normal procedure which you do for coping normal file. Copy the .prpt file and past in you machine and then open the file and start edit